# Change action after redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, model

I am still learning about the Rails architecture so if this should be done another way, I'm ok with that.  I have a simple Index view that includes a model/view that allows input of user parameters.  After the form is submitted I redirect back to the Index view which now shows the form as before AND the results.  I currently have cobbled together a way to change the view based upon redirect or first render but I was wondering if there is a clean way to determine if the view has been redirected based upon looking at params or something?

```
# PATCH/PUT /stuffs/1 or /stuffs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stuff.update(stuff_params)
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'index' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stuff }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @stuff.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You certainly can read params sent, can you share the code from that controller (by editing the question and adding it) and also let us know what the param and value is that you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, Rockwell.  I'm new at this and forgot I had posted a question.  Please forgive.  I was not familiar with params[:item] at the time but thanks for responding.  So all is well now.  Thanks for offering the help though.

Comment: no worries, glad you got it worked out!